# I want to know why this id problem happen

Tags: javascript

If I write like this

```
const title = document.getElementById("title");


function handleClick() {
    title.style.color = "red";
}

title.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

it works, but if I write like this

```
const title = document.getElementById("#title");


function handleClick() {
    title.style.color = "red";
}

title.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```

it doesn't work. please explain why this happen,,Thank you.

Comment: What does your element look like?

Comment: Apples are not oranges. It's not useful to pass a selector to a method which can't handle selectors.

Comment: `document.getElementById("#title")` would require the HTML to be `<my-element id="#title" />`

Answer (score 1):

You probably have some html like;

```html
<div id='title'>My Title</div>
```

Here, `document.getElementById("title")` will work, because `title` matches the `id`.

However, if you do it like so:

```
document.getElementById("#title")
```

`#title` does not match the `id` of the `<div>`, because it should be `id='#title'`

---

```js
const test_1 = document.getElementById('title');
const test_2 = document.getElementById('#title');

console.log(test_1);   // OK   -> id='title' does match .getElementById('title')
console.log(test_2);   // NULL -> id='title' does NOT match .getElementById('#title')
```

```html
<div id='title'>
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help. I finally find what is wrong with my code. Thank you for your help again.

Comment: Glad it helped! Please consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) or [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) any answers that might have helped you. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Answer (score 1):

`#` is a CSS selector and can't be used with javascript. Javascript identifies elements by their ID using `document.getElementById("ID")` method. Similarly, you can use `.` as a CSS selector but in JavaScript, you need to get elements of a class using `document.getElementsByClassName("CLASSNAME")`.
If you use `document.getElementById("#id")`, then JavaScript will look for an element with id set as `id = "#id"` and not `id = "id"`.

Comment: A small fix, JavaScript can use CSS selectors to pick elements, take a look at [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) and [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

Answer (score 0):

Because, to put it simple, `#` is not part of the id but rather a delimiter to identify ids similar as `.` for classes

Comment: But my teacher's code works well. This is why I am confused. My code isn't work, but my teacher's code works...My teacher write '#title' but his code works well...

Comment: @Juzzn Take a look at [this my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67723767/i-want-to-know-why-this-id-problem-happen#comment119705828_67723887) and follow the links, perhaps your teacher's code differs from yours.